# Why is wp_new_user_notification not working?

Tags: user-registration, wp-mail

I don't like to use a plugin so I made use of [`user registration`](http://www.cozmoslabs.com/1012-wordpress-user-registration-template-and-custom-user-profile-fields/) custom signup page and it's not sending any emails.

At first everything was working. Then I added some functions to change the "from" and the "email" using `wp_mail_from`, which worked. Then I decided to personalize the email as well by adding some conditions in the  `wp_new_user_notification`. Then it doesn't send any emails any more.

Here's the whole template code:

`

```
<?php require_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/registration.php');

    /* Check if users can register. */
    $registration = get_option( 'users_can_register' );

    /* If user registered, input info. */
    if ( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) && $_POST['action'] == 'adduser' ) {
        $user_pass = wp_generate_password();
        $userdata = array(
            'user_pass' => $user_pass,
            'user_login' => esc_attr( $_POST['user_name'] ),
            'first_name' => esc_attr( $_POST['first_name'] ),
            'last_name' => esc_attr( $_POST['last_name'] ),
            'user_email' => esc_attr( $_POST['email'] ),
        );

        function make_blog_name_from_name($name) {
                return 'RNA Administrator';
                }
                add_filter('wp_mail_from_name', 'make_blog_name_from_name');

        function from_mail($content_type){
                    return 'admin@rnaforum.com';
                }
                add_filter('wp_mail_from','from_mail');

        if ( !$userdata['user_login'] )
            $error = __('A username is required for registration.', 'frontendprofile');
        elseif ( username_exists($userdata['user_login']) )
            $error = __('Sorry, that username already exists!', 'frontendprofile');

        elseif ( !is_email($userdata['user_email'], true) )
            $error = __('You must enter a valid email address.', 'frontendprofile');
        elseif ( email_exists($userdata['user_email']) )
            $error = __('Sorry, that email address is already used!', 'frontendprofile');

    else{
            $new_user = wp_insert_user( $userdata );
            if ( !function_exists('wp_new_user_notification') ) {
            function wp_new_user_notification($user_id, $plaintext_pass){

                $new_user = new WP_User($user_id);

                $user_login = stripslashes($user->user_login);
                $user_email = stripslashes($user->user_email);

                // The blogname option is escaped with esc_html on the way into the database in sanitize_option
                // we want to reverse this for the plain text arena of emails.
                $blogname = wp_specialchars_decode(get_option('blogname'), ENT_QUOTES);

                $message  = sprintf(__('New user registration on your site %s:'), $blogname) . "\r\n\r\n";
                $message .= sprintf(__('Username: %s'), $user_login) . "\r\n\r\n";
                $message .= sprintf(__('E-mail: %s'), $user_email) . "\r\n";

                @wp_mail(get_option('admin_email'), sprintf(__('[%s] New User Registration'), $blogname), $message);

                if ( empty($plaintext_pass) )
                    return;

                $message  = sprintf(__('Username: %s'), $user_login) . "\r\n";
                $message .= sprintf(__('Password: %s'), $plaintext_pass) . "\r\n";
                $message .= "Thank you";

                wp_mail($user_email, sprintf(__('[%s] Your username and password'), $blogname), $message);

            }   
            }

        }

    }

    // calling the header.php
    get_header();?>

    <div id="container">
        <div id="content">
                <div class="entry-content">
                </div>
            <!-- REGISTER FORM STARTS HERE -->

        <?php if ( is_user_logged_in() && !current_user_can( 'create_users' ) ) : ?>

            <p class="log-in-out alert">
            <?php printf( __('You are logged in as <a href="%1$s" title="%2$s">%2$s</a>.  You don\'t need another account.', 'frontendprofile'), get_author_posts_url( $curauth->ID ), $user_identity ); ?> <a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( get_permalink() ); ?>" title="<?php _e('Log out of this account', 'frontendprofile'); ?>"><?php _e('Logout &raquo;', 'frontendprofile'); ?></a>
            </p><!-- .log-in-out .alert -->

        <?php elseif ( $new_user ) : ?>

            <p class="alert">
            <?php
                if ( current_user_can( 'create_users' ) )
                    printf( __('A user account for %1$s has been created.', 'frontendprofile'), $_POST['user-name'] );
                else 
                    printf( __('Thank you for registering, %1$s.', 'frontendprofile'), $_POST['user-name'] );
                    printf( __('<br/>Please check your email address. That\'s where you\'ll recieve your login password.<br/> (It might go into your spam folder)', 'frontendprofile') );
            ?>
            </p><!-- .alert -->

        <?php else : ?>

            <?php if ( $error ) : ?>
                <p class="error">
                    <?php echo $error; ?>
                </p><!-- .error -->
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ( current_user_can( 'create_users' ) && $registration ) : ?>
                <p class="alert">
                    <?php _e('Users can register themselves or you can manually create users here.', 'frontendprofile'); ?>
                </p><!-- .alert -->
            <?php elseif ( current_user_can( 'create_users' ) ) : ?>
                <p class="alert">
                    <?php _e('Users cannot currently register themselves, but you can manually create users here.', 'frontendprofile'); ?>
                </p><!-- .alert -->
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ( $registration || current_user_can( 'create_users' ) ) : ?>

            <form method="post" id="adduser" class="user-forms" action="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>">


                <strong>Name</strong>

                <p class="form-username">
                    <label for="user_name"><?php _e('Username (required)', 'frontendprofile'); ?></label>
                    <input class="text-input" name="user_name" type="text" id="user_name" value="<?php if ( $error ) echo wp_specialchars( $_POST['user_name'], 1 ); ?>" />
                </p><!-- .form-username -->

                <p class="first_name">
                    <label for="first_name"><?php _e('First Name', 'frontendprofile'); ?></label>
                    <input class="text-input" name="first_name" type="text" id="first_name" value="<?php if ( $error ) echo wp_specialchars( $_POST['first_name'], 1 ); ?>" />
                </p><!-- .first_name -->

                <p class="last_name">
                    <label for="last_name"><?php _e('Last Name', 'frontendprofile'); ?></label>
                    <input class="text-input" name="last_name" type="text" id="last_name" value="<?php if ( $error ) echo wp_specialchars( $_POST['last_name'], 1 ); ?>" />
                </p><!-- .last_name -->

                <strong>Contact Info</strong>

                <p class="form-email">
                    <label for="email"><?php _e('E-mail (required)', 'frontendprofile'); ?></label>
                    <input class="text-input" name="email" type="text" id="email" value="<?php if ( $error ) echo wp_specialchars( $_POST['email'], 1 ); ?>" />
                </p><!-- .form-email -->

                <p class="form-submit">
                    <?php echo $referer; ?>
                    <input name="adduser" type="submit" id="addusersub" class="submit button" value="<?php if ( current_user_can( 'create_users' ) ) _e('Add User', 'frontendprofile'); else _e('Register', 'frontendprofile'); ?>" />
                    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'add-user' ) ?>
                    <input name="action" type="hidden" id="action" value="adduser" />
                </p><!-- .form-submit -->

            </form><!-- #adduser -->

            <?php endif; ?>

        <?php endif; ?>

<!-- REGISTER FORM ENDS HERE -->`
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. I have removed the new declaration of wp_new_user_notification function from the code as it would consider the new function only if it is put in a plugin. That's how the priority is taken.

```
<?php
/* Check if users can register. */
$registration = get_option( 'users_can_register' );

/* If user registered, input info. */
if ( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) && $_POST['action'] == 'adduser' ) {
    $user_pass = wp_generate_password();
    $userdata = array(
        'user_pass' => $user_pass,
        'user_login' => esc_attr( $_POST['user_name'] ),
        'first_name' => esc_attr( $_POST['first_name'] ),
        'last_name' => esc_attr( $_POST['last_name'] ),
        'user_email' => esc_attr( $_POST['email'] ),
    );

    function make_blog_name_from_name($name) {
            return 'RNA Administrator';
            }
            add_filter('wp_mail_from_name', 'make_blog_name_from_name');

    function from_mail($content_type){
                return 'admin@rnaforum.com';
            }
            add_filter('wp_mail_from','from_mail');

    if ( !$userdata['user_login'] )
        $error = __('A username is required for registration.', 'frontendprofile');
    elseif ( username_exists($userdata['user_login']) )
        $error = __('Sorry, that username already exists!', 'frontendprofile');

    elseif ( !is_email($userdata['user_email']) )
        $error = __('You must enter a valid email address.', 'frontendprofile');
    elseif ( email_exists($userdata['user_email']) )
        $error = __('Sorry, that email address is already used!', 'frontendprofile');

else{
        $new_user = wp_insert_user( $userdata );

        wp_new_user_notification($new_user, $user_pass);

    }

}

// calling the header.php
get_header();?>

<div id="container">
    <div id="content">
            <div class="entry-content">
            </div>
        <!-- REGISTER FORM STARTS HERE -->

    <?php if ( is_user_logged_in() && !current_user_can( 'create_users' ) ) : ?>

        <p class="log-in-out alert">
        <?php printf( __('You are logged in as <a href="%1$s" title="%2$s">%2$s</a>.  You don\'t need another account.', 'frontendprofile'), get_author_posts_url( $curauth->ID ), $user_identity ); ?> <a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( get_permalink() ); ?>" title="<?php _e('Log out of this account', 'frontendprofile'); ?>"><?php _e('Logout &raquo;', 'frontendprofile'); ?></a>
        </p><!-- .log-in-out .alert -->

    <?php elseif ( @$new_user ) : ?>

        <p class="alert">
        <?php
            if ( current_user_can( 'create_users' ) )
                printf( __('A user account for %1$s has been created.', 'frontendprofile'), $_POST['user_name'] );
            else 
                printf( __('Thank you for registering, %1$s.', 'frontendprofile'), $_POST['user-name'] );
                printf( __('<br/>Please check your email address. That\'s where you\'ll recieve your login password.<br/> (It might go into your spam folder)', 'frontendprofile') );
        ?>
        </p><!-- .alert -->

    <?php else : ?>

        <?php if ( $error ) : ?>
            <p class="error">
                <?php echo $error; ?>
            </p><!-- .error -->
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ( current_user_can( 'create_users' ) && $registration ) : ?>
            <p class="alert">
                <?php _e('Users can register themselves or you can manually create users here.', 'frontendprofile'); ?>
            </p><!-- .alert -->
        <?php elseif ( current_user_can( 'create_users' ) ) : ?>
            <p class="alert">
                <?php _e('Users cannot currently register themselves, but you can manually create users here.', 'frontendprofile'); ?>
            </p><!-- .alert -->
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ( $registration || current_user_can( 'create_users' ) ) : ?>

        <form method="post" id="adduser" class="user-forms" action="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>">


            <strong>Name</strong>

            <p class="form-username">
                <label for="user_name"><?php _e('Username (required)', 'frontendprofile'); ?></label>
                <input class="text-input" name="user_name" type="text" id="user_name" value="<?php if ( $error ) echo wp_specialchars( $_POST['user_name'], 1 ); ?>" />
            </p><!-- .form-username -->

            <p class="first_name">
                <label for="first_name"><?php _e('First Name', 'frontendprofile'); ?></label>
                <input class="text-input" name="first_name" type="text" id="first_name" value="<?php if ( $error ) echo wp_specialchars( $_POST['first_name'], 1 ); ?>" />
            </p><!-- .first_name -->

            <p class="last_name">
                <label for="last_name"><?php _e('Last Name', 'frontendprofile'); ?></label>
                <input class="text-input" name="last_name" type="text" id="last_name" value="<?php if ( $error ) echo wp_specialchars( $_POST['last_name'], 1 ); ?>" />
            </p><!-- .last_name -->

            <strong>Contact Info</strong>

            <p class="form-email">
                <label for="email"><?php _e('E-mail (required)', 'frontendprofile'); ?></label>
                <input class="text-input" name="email" type="text" id="email" value="<?php if ( $error ) echo wp_specialchars( $_POST['email'], 1 ); ?>" />
            </p><!-- .form-email -->

            <p class="form-submit">
                <input name="adduser" type="submit" id="addusersub" class="submit button" value="<?php if ( current_user_can( 'create_users' ) ) _e('Add User', 'frontendprofile'); else _e('Register', 'frontendprofile'); ?>" />
                <?php wp_nonce_field( 'add-user' ) ?>
                <input name="action" type="hidden" id="action" value="adduser" />
            </p><!-- .form-submit -->

        </form><!-- #adduser -->

        <?php endif; ?>

    <?php endif; ?>
```